# How to fix "upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream" on secure Nginx

Tags: python, nginx, load-balancing, grpc, grpc-python

I configure my nginx:

```
user root;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent"';

server {
        listen 80 ssl http2;

        ssl_certificate     MY_PATH/ssl_truststore.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key MY_PATH/ssl_keystore.pem;
        ssl_password_file /root/passwd;

        server_name my-server-name;

        access_log logs/access.log main;

        location / {
            # Replace localhost:50051 with the address and port of your gRPC server
            # The 'grpc://' prefix is optional; unencrypted gRPC is the default
            grpc_pass grpc://my-server-name:1234;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to configure secure nginx L7 load balancing for SSL grpc server. On non-secure grpc server non-secure nginx works well. But on secure I got an error:

```
2018/07/20 07:00:42 [error] 6988#6988:
*1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream,
client: some-ip, server:my-server-name, 
request: "POST XXXX HTTP/2.0", 
upstream: "grpc://my-server-name:1234", host: "my-server-name"
```

I tried to found the resolution of this problem, but nothing fit for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to change

```
grpc_pass grpcs://my-server-name:1234;
```

The resolution was found.